# SQLAlchemy, Foreign Key Refering for various tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can i do a foreign key refer to id to multiple tables?

```
class HistoryActivation(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'active_control'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_entity = Column(Integer) #This one refer to any entity (id) that has a relation with this class.
    date = Column(DATE)
    user = Column(String(120))
    active = Column(BOOLEAN)

class Person(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) 
    name = Column(String(50))

    history_activation = relationship("HistoryActivation",
            primaryjoin="HistoryActivation.id_entidade == Person.id")

class Company(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'companies'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))

    history_activation = relationship("HistoryActivation",
            primaryjoin="HistoryActivation.id_entidade == Company.id")


class Whatever(Base): ...
```

So, id_entity refer to id to various tables, something like:

```
    id_entity = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Person.id or Company.id or Whatever.id').
```

Is possible to tell ForeignKey can refer more than one relation?

Comment: The primary key column on subclasses is supposed to be a foreign key to the base class's primary key. Not sure what you're asking here.